# Subtype that accepts only certain string values

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to find the best way to implement types that only accept certain string values, e.g.:

```
export type Plan = {
  client_uuid: string;
  name: string;
  kind: string;
};
```

I would like a subtype of `Plan` called for example `Financial` that accepts only the strings `"protection"` or `"insurance"`, and another subtype of `Plan` that accepts only `"mortgage"`.

Is the only way to do this?

```
export type Plan = {
  client_uuid: string;
  name: string;
};

export type Financial extends Plan {
  kind: "protection" | "insurance"
}

export type MortgagePlan extends Plan {
  kind: "mortgage"
}
```

It seems like this isn't a proper subtype as I would understand it - that it shouldn't be necessary to re-add the kind property each time the type is extended. Can I specify a Financial Plan is a type of Plan with a restricted `kind` field?

What are the options here?

Comment: It seems like `Plan` shouldn't be exposed, that's a base type then your consumers access `type Plan = Financial | MortgagePlan`. Or maybe something like https://tsplay.dev/wRAR1W would work. Without more context it's hard to say

Comment: Yes Jon, that is true

Answer (score 1):

You can't extend types, it's only valid for the interfaces. You can use an *intersection* to make sure that all fields from `Plan` are in place:

```
export type Plan = {
  client_uuid: string;
  name: string;
};

export type Financial = Plan & {
  kind: 'protection' | 'insurance';
};

export type MortgagePlan = Plan & {
  kind: 'mortgage';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export type Plan<T extends boolean> = {
  client_uuid: string;
  name: string;
  kind: T  extends true ?  "protection" | "insurance" : "mortgage"
};


// Plan<true> is Financial
// Plan<false> is MortgagePlan
```

multi-target expansion plan:

```
interface TypeMap {
  Financial:  "protection" | "insurance"
  MortgagePlan: "mortgage"
}


export type Plan<T extends keyof TypeMap> = {
  client_uuid: string;
  name: string;
  kind: TypeMap[T]
};
```

Comment: this is not scalable. What if the third option appears?

Comment: I agree I was just about to ask how to scale it

Comment: @wonderflame if it need to expand we can use `type TypeMap = {Financial: "protection" | "insurance"...}` to create multiple types easily

Comment: well, your answer doesn't cover that. I would rather accept `T extends string` in that case rather than a boolean. Anyway, this approach is fragile, since some new fields may also appear

Comment: OK it's not extensible, but for my use case that's the point. The strings it accepts are never going to change and we need to be strict about what we accept

Comment: @wonderflame too bad i never want to rewrite something like `Plan<'protection' | '...'>`